# extract domain names from source code thoroughly

Tags: bash

i've been searching for bash script to extract domain names, i found a few tips using `grep`, but they only search certain TLD like `.com` or certain patterns like `google([A-Za-z\-]*?\\*?)\.com`.

i'm working on a project which depends on other open source projects, i want to thoroughly search and extract all domain names in the source code, for security reasons

i'm thinking to use something like this: https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat, which is list of all public top level domains, then search and extract from entire source code that matches all domains from `public_suffix_list.dat`

P.S.

- `public_suffix_list.dat` has comment lines, but it's easy to remove those and leaving only TLS lists
- for source code, if iterating entire source code recursively cost too much, do one file thoroughly is also ok, i can generate a file list and do it one by one

is this possible for bash script? thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using one of the command line url extractors such as urlscan they take input and supply a list of all the url you can also have them opened in a browser if you want.

Comment: @JasonCroyle, thanks for the quick update, i'm testing urlscan, will update later

Comment: There is a couple of these url extractors out there the two most common are urlview and urlscan there is also a couple very well tested regex for url that work excellent as well iterating of a file like that can be done but you'll never have an up to date list and it would be hugely inefficient.

Comment: @JasonCroyle, thanks, i looked at urlscan's github page, it's using https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt to detect domain names, and tested from my end, this tool is great, it works for like 99.99% cases, there's one big xml file which got urlscan stuck, but that's ok, i can ignore that one